# How to make have vertical lines instead of horizontal lines in kableextra R

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

Are there any way to remove horizontal lines in `kable_styling()` and have vertical lines instead when reporting rmarkdown as pdf?

```r
library(kableExtra)
head(mtcars) %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_styling()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is a combination of `booktabs` and `border_right`, e.g.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
head(mtcars) %>%
  kbl(booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling() %>% 
 column_spec(c(1:ncol(mtcars)),
    border_right = T
  )
```